# How to handle client server communication in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, client

I have two Perl scripts that are supposed to do the following job:

Server starts and wait for the client to connect.
The client connects and istantly send an XML file.
Server reads XML file and starts a couple of threads.
Each thread receive $client socket as a parameter and once they're done they have to send the output back to the client.
Meanwhile the client is waiting for messages to arrive, he's supposed to print those messages on the command line.

Now my problem is that I don't know how to implement the last part. I tryed to use the receive method but both programs get stuck if I do that.

Server side:

```
my @threads;
$server = IO::Socket::INET->new(
            Listen => 1,                
            LocalAddr => 'localhost', 
            LocalPort => '8080', 
            Proto => 'tcp'
) or die "Can't crete socket!\n";
$client = $server->accept;
open FILE, ">".$filename or die "Can't open file!\n";
while (<$client>) {
    print FILE $_;  
}
close FILE;

# READ FILE AND DO SOME OTHER STUFFS
push @threads, threads ->create(\&subroutine1, $parameters, $client);
# OTHER STUFFS
push @threads, threads ->create(\&subroutine2, $parameters, $client);
# MORE THREADS...

sub subroutine1 {
    my @pars= @_;
    my $parameters = $pars[0];
    my $client = $pars[1];
    my $sub1 = `perl other_script.pl $parameters`;
    $client->send($mem);
}
```

Client side:

```
my $server = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    PeerAddr => 'localhost',
    PeerPort => '8080',
    Proto => 'tcp'
) or die "Can't create client socket!\n";
open FILE, $filename;
while (<FILE>) {
    print $server $_;   
}
close FILE;
# HOW DO I READ INFORMATIONS?
$server->close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put the send part into the children/worker threads, it'll be jumbled.

> Q: Why did the multi-threaded chicken cross the road?
>
> A: other to side. To the get

Instead, have the parent/boss thread collect the results of the children, sort the data if necessary, serialise, then send as a whole.

You read with the [`recv` function](http://p3rl.org/recv), also available as a method in [`IO::Socket`](http://p3rl.org/IO::Socket#METHODS).

Comment: How can I retrieve the result? I am using join() right now in this way: foreach (@threads) {
   $msg = $_->join();
   print "$msg\n"; #$client->send($msg);
  } but print does not work, I mean it prints nothing.

Comment: Ok never mind print works but send does not, the two threads get stuck just like before. The client works like that right now: while (<$server>) {
  print $_;
 }

Comment: I even tryed $server->recv($msg, $length, 0); but I don't know how to define the message length actually.

Comment: You are messing with a very low-level thing and are expected to handle the resulting complexity yourself. You lack a protocol that defines who sends what in which format, and what the communication partner has to expect. Instead of inventing a crappy one by yourself, my recommendation is to forget about sockets and switch to HTTP. It already proved its worth a trillion times. You gain interoperability with a ridiculous amount of software, and you gain a huge ecosystem for scaling in any direction. tl;dr: Write a web application with Plack, the code will be shorter and more maintainable.